# What does \_. means in Vim?

Tags: regular-expression, terminal

```
what does \_. means in vim ?  explain to me character by character
```

Response from chatgpt:

```
In Vim regular expressions, \_. is a sequence that represents any character including a newline. 
Here is an explanation of each character:

The backslash \ is an escape character that is used to indicate that the following character has a special meaning in Vim regular expressions. In this case, it is used to escape the underscore character _.
The underscore _ matches any single character, but it does not match newline characters by default.
The dot . matches any character except newline characters.

Therefore, when you combine the \ and _ characters with the dot . character, you get \_., which matches any character, including newline characters
```

Comment: The underscore _ matches any single character, but it does NOT match newline characters by default.
    The dot . matches any character EXCEPT newline characters.

Therefore, when you combine the \ and _ characters with the dot . character, you get \_., which matches any character, INCLUDING newline characters ???
No+No= Yes ?????

Comment: Just… don't trust ChatGPT, generally. It's good at producing convincing BS (at _best_).

Comment: LOL. i agree with you this one.  I have being using for sometime and realized many time it is a twist and turning tongue..  although sometime it does producing usable data..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the explanation of the Vim doc:

```
\_. Matches any single character or end-of-line.
    Careful: "\_.*" matches all text to the end of the buffer!
```

```
\_x Where "x" is any of the characters above: The character class with
    end-of-line added
```

`\_` is an atom modifier that add the new line to some atom matching like `.` or `\s`, or`\d` where:

- `.` match any character but new line `\_.` match any character including new line.
- `\s` match any space character but new line `\_s` match any space including new line.
- `\d` match any digit character and not new line `\_d` match any digit or new line.

Comment: a ya.. that's more like it.. that's what i found out when tried on vim several times...
so the gptchat is totally bs on this stuff.  a lot of bs i have encountered on it.

Comment: ok.. now that you explained like this.. i understood.. thanks a lot. 
i was like starring on vim help :h \_ ...but totally can't understand anything.. However your explanation is wonderful. Thanks